# How do I link accounts from a remote IdP to my local Drupal Accounts?

Tags: 8, users

I'm using using the `simplesamlphp_auth` module and I've configured a remote IdP in my `simplesamlphp` config files. At this point, when I'm on the login screen, I see a link to login with my IdP, and the IdP login/2FA flow goes through just fine.

When I'm done, I'm taken back to my Drupal site (the IdP is configured to redirect to `/admin/content`) but I am *not authenticated* in the Drupal application. I had set the option to "Synchronize user name on every login" in the configuration of the `simplesamlphp_auth` module but I guess it's not doing what I thought it would. I also configured it to use the `mail` attribute that the IdP is supposed to give as the unique identifier.

Ideally what I would like is that only people that can login through the IdP *and* have a Drupal account with the same email are able to be authenticated. Right now that'll only happen if the user manually logs in again with their local Drupal account after going through the remote IdP.

**How can I automatically log in users into their local Drupal account after they have authenticated with the remote IdP, and only if they match the email addresses from both accounts?**

Comment: I believe there is a hook_simplesaml_auth_login_finalize or something of that nature that should let you insert logic. The last time I did this, once they were authenticated from the IDP the account was created automatically... are there any errors or anything?

Comment: @Kevin I don't see any errors on the page when they come back from the IDP (other than the user is not authenticated on Drupal). I'll check the logs and report back. I'll also have to try to find this hook you mentioned. The only other difference I would note is that I already have existing Drupal accounts I want to link to the IDP accounts, so I am not looking to _create_ accounts after login.

Comment: Based on your description, I think the Hook I'm looking for is `hook_simplesamlphp_auth_existing_user`, which _should_ be called after authenticating via the remote IDP. I threw together a simple module that implements that hook, but it doesn't seem to be called after authenticating, and there are no errors in the Drupal log either. The logic inside the hook definition seems to be exactly what I need (look up by `mail` attribute and log the user in).